# Representing a list of items in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Suppose you have a list of items (instructions in a function, posts on a blog, episodes in a TV series etc) that need to be kept in order, what is the recommended way to store them in Neo4j? Two possibilities that come to mind:

1. Assuming the items don't already have a suitable property for sorting by, assign them incrementing sequence numbers.
2. Use a linked list of nodes.

Which of these is typically recommended? Or is there a third option I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a linked list.

Sequence numbers still have to be sorted, which is unnecessary overhead. And to do the sort, neo4j has to iterate through every node in the sequence, even if you are only interested in a small part of the sequence.